# Are GitHub personal access tokens single use (then they expire/delete)?

Tags: github, command-line, passwords, token, two-factor-authentication

Can GitHub personal access tokens be set to single use only?

I'm reading [the GitHub Personal Access Token setup guide](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line). It appears that I create a 'token' to eliminate the need for my 2FA code when using GitHub from the command line.

I want this token to either expire after I use it, or I want the ability to delete it permanently somehow after I use it. Is this possible? Otherwise it seems to defeat the purpose of 2FA because if somebody got my token they could get into my GitHub without 2FA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to `Delete` a single token or `Revoke All` tokens in Github.